# ¿Cómo hago una consulta que muestre pedidos de dos años? En SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Para sacar solo pedidos de una año he puesto un intervalo, con formato YYYYMMDD:
[image: En este caso quería pedidos desde 1 de enero de 2009 hasta el 31 de diciembre de 2009. Hasta aquí todo bien.]

Pero para sacar todos los pedidos de 2009 y del 2006 he probado a añadir al intervalo anterior un OR y hacer otro intervalo de principio a fin de 2006.
El problema es que salen pedidos de otros años fuera del intervalo.

[image]

Soy nuevo en SQL, cualquier información ayuda. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 4):

Partamos de la base que

```
SELECT campo FROM tabla WHERE 1
```

Trae todos los registros. Es como poner `WHERE 1=1`, que siempre se cumple. Lo mismo se aplica a `WHERE 20060101`. En tanto, añadir `AND 1` a una consulta no agrega ni quita nada al comportamiento del resto de la cláusula `WHERE`. Por tanto tu sentencia se trae todo

```
WHERE (FechaPedido between 20090101 AND 20091231)
   OR 20060101 -- todos los campos cumplen
   AND 20061231 -- no cambia en nada lo anterior
```

La cláusula debiera ser

```
WHERE FechaPedido between 20090101 AND 20091231
   OR FechaPedido between 20060101 AND 20061231
```

---

**Bonus Track: paréntesis defensivos**

Siempre ante la duda puedes añadir unos "paréntesis defensivos" que hagan más evidente cuál es el scope del `OR`.

```
WHERE (
      (FechaPedido between 20090101 AND 20091231)
   OR (FechaPedido between 20060101 AND 20061231)
)
```

Esto se vuelve necesario a medida que usas el OR para declarar conjuntos de condiciones que no deseas mezclar entre sí

Por ejemplo si además de la fecha quisieras filtrar por el estado del pedido, lo siguiente no restringe el estado de ambos rangos de fecha, ni acota los pedidos entregados o cancelados a las fechas indicadas

```
WHERE FechaPedido between 20090101 AND 20091231
   OR FechaPedido between 20060101 AND 20061231
  AND EstadoPedido = 'Entregado'
   OR EstadoPedido = 'Cancelado'
```

Pero la versión con paréntesis le dice al query optimizer que el OR se refiere únicamente a la admisibilidad de dos rangos de fecha (grupo 1) y la la admisibilidad de dos estados (grupo 2)

```
WHERE (
      (FechaPedido between 20090101 AND 20091231)
   OR (FechaPedido between 20060101 AND 20061231)
) AND (
      EstadoPEdido = 'Entregado'
   OR EstadoPEdido = 'Cancelado'
)
```